# Error subsetting with grep, pipe(), and read.table() - initial data load

Tags: r, pipe, subset, read.table

I'm trying to subset data from 2,075,259 rows using `grep` within `pipe()` and `read.table()`.  In this case, the search query is two consecutive dates. However, there seems to be something wrong with my `grep` syntax:

```
download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2Fhousehold_power_consumption.zip",
 "file.zip")
unzip("file.zip")

data <- read.table(pipe('grep "^[1-2]/2/2007" "household_power_consumption.txt"'))

Error in read.table(pipe("grep \"^[1-2]/2/2007\" \"household_power_consumption.txt\"")) : 
  no lines available in input
```

I've been able to do this using `findstr` (see below), which is fine, except I want the code to work outside Windows, and I believe `findstr` is Windows-specific.

```
data <- read.table(pipe("findstr /B /R ^[1-2]/2/2007 household_power_consumption.txt"))  ## this works
```

Any thoughts?  (FYI, I'm aware I can also speed up the data load with arguments like sep = ";", na.strings = "?", colClasses, etc.)

Comment: Do you have `grep` installed on Windows? What machine are you actually running on? You can't really guarantee that functions/programs outside of R will exist on other machines.

Comment: Well, this works fine for me, after changing `https` to `http`, because that's not supported by `download.file()`, at least in my R version. So is this Windows?

Comment: @MrFlick, I just installed Windows Grep from http://download.cnet.com/Windows-Grep/3000-2351_4-75805915.html and restarted.  I'm still unable to get it, although I am able to do so using the Windows Grep app itself.

My Windows info is `release` = `"7 x64"` and `version` = `"build 7601, Service Pack 1"`

(Sorry for any repeat notices.)  Also, if grep is not system independent, what would be the best way for me to do the subsetting with `read.table()` that would be cross-platform?

Comment: @DanielFletcher So you can run the exact grep command from the command prompt and it returns the lines you want, but it doesn't work from inside R with the exact same command? Was `grep` added to the path such that you can run it from anywhere? I don't have enough experience to recommend something guaranteed to work cross platform. I *think* the `sqldf` package can filter records during reading rather than after like most native R functions. `fread` from `data.table` might be reasonably fast as well.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks for the feedback.  In short, I'm unsure how to get it to run from the cmd line.  I tried installing grep gnu from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm and it looks like this is beyond my commandline skills.  I will definitely consider `sqldf`.
@GaborCsardi, do you happen to have a link or tips on how I can make sure I'm installing the GNU Grep properly and loading it from the command line?  (Again, I have very minimal cmd experience and am struggling to figure it out with online research.)  Thanks.

Comment: A more portable solution is to read all the data and then use R grepl or like to filter rows. With data.table package's fread(), this will be much faster than with read.table.